# Finding pairs of double conditions in the same SQL table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

It's probably very simple but I am new to SQL. I have an address table with 3 columns: city, state, zipcode. I want to be able to pull a list of specific cities each paired with one specific state so I wrote a query like this:

```
select ZIPCode from USZipCodes where 
(CityName='New York' and StateAbbr='NY') or 
(CityName='Philadelphia' and StateAbbr='PA')
```

However, I need to repeat this for a list of 100+ city/state pairs so I am wondering how to simplify this?

Comment: Without another table to limit by or some other criteria to limit by what you're doing is as simple as it gets.

Comment: You should explain more about your intent.

Comment: Are you looking for all distinct pairs of city and state?  Or do you only want a subset?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your time to make a lookup table with all those pairs, then in your query you simply `JOIN` to that lookup table:

```
select ZIPCode 
from USZipCodes a
JOIN pairs b
 ON a.CityName = b.CityName
 AND a.StateAbbr = b.StateAbbr
```

But otherwise, what you have is fine.

I'd suggest using Excel to construct the sql since you have so many to list out.

It's also likely that there aren't many pairs that need to be explicitly defined, ie: New York, CO probably not an issue, to find the prevalence and potentially limit need for listing pairs you could check which cities have multiple state abbreviations:

```
SELECT CityName
FROM USZipCodes
GROUP BY CityName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT StateAbbr)>1
```

Comment: Yes, I have a list of 100+ unique city/state pairs for which I need to pull up zipcode from the address table.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it you could use the tuple syntax.

```
select CityName, StateAbbr, ZIPCode 
from USZipCodes 
where (CityName, StateAbbr) IN (
    ('New York', 'NY') ,
    ('Philadelphia','PA') 
)
```